# Spin 1/2 - finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Hamiltonian that includes d/dz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism, eigenvalue

Suppose a spin 1/2 system is described by the Hamiltonian

$$H = -αp_{z}s_{z}$$

and I have to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

The Hamiltonian in matrix form that I wrote is

$$\hat{H} = \frac{i\alpha\hbar^{2}}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

My question is, how do I go about calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors if there is a derivative in the Hamiltonian?

Comment: This operator might look more familiar if you move the derivative through the (constant) matrix and write it a the right of the expression?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider an eigenstate of the form $\Psi = \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1(z) \\
\psi_2(z) 
\end{pmatrix}  $ and put it in the time independent Schrödinger's equation $\hat{H} \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1(z) \\
\psi_2(z) 
\end{pmatrix} = E\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1(z) \\
\psi_2(z) 
\end{pmatrix}$

(which will give you two equations in $\psi_1(z)$ and $\psi_2(z)$. In this case, these equations are uncoupled).

You can similarly solve time dependent problems too (e.g. spin 1/2 particle in a rotating magnetic field).

Have a look at the wikipedia page of [Schrödinger–Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) for some examples.